# Parameter to reference a certain cell to input the date into a URL

Tags: vba, excel, url-parameters

I have a workbook that is pulling data for every hour of the day from an internal website. The VBA script is built to pull data 24 times (each hour).

What I'm trying to do is set up a parameter that will reference a certain cell (Master!K5) which will contain the date I need to pull. I want to be able to have that cell referenced automatically and input the date for each URL in the VBA script.

Is this a possibility?

```
With Sheets("C 0000-0100").Activate
        Cells.Select
        Selection.ClearContents
   End With
   With CaseHour01.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://xxxx-xxxxx.xxxxxx.com/reports/functionRollup?reportFormat=HTML&warehouseId=xxxx&processId=1002967&startDateDay=2014/04/01&maxIntradayDays=1&spanType=Intraday&startDateIntraday=2014/04/01&startHourIntraday=0&startMinuteIntraday=0&endDateIntraday=2014/04/01&endHourIntraday=1&endMinuteIntraday=0 " _
        , Destination:=Range("'C 0000-0100'!$A$1"))
        .Name = "00.000&reportFormat=HTML&processId=01002967"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = """function-4300006644"""
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
   End With
```

Comment: If you have code you should post it - it's much easier than guessing exactly how you're already doing this.

Comment: Also the format of **starthour** and **endhour** is important, so give us some examples.

Comment: Please excuse me for not responding quickly, I was out on vacation and just returned. I have edited the post to include the code I am using.

Comment: So, in the web address from the code above, includes the start date and start and end time. I have this code repeated for every hour, what I need to figure out is how to have the date from a cell on a sheet be automatically entered into each URL. The date is the same for each URL every day.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to locate a solution after an extensive google search. Here is what I found:

When a date appears in a URL, enter

```
" & Format(Range("'Sheet1'!E2"), "yyyy/mm/dd") & "
```

where the date should be. This will allow you to select a certain Cell and input that value in the URL. (You would change the format of the date based on how it appears in the original URL.